# Save Data Source in Crystal Server

Tags: crystal-reports, datasource, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

I'm new to Crystal Reports/Crystal Server. Hope someone can enlighten me.

In SSRS, there's a thing called Shared Data Source wherein you can configure a data source like the server and database settings. This data source can then be used by multiple reports. This is very convenient especially if you would change the server name (ex: Production to UAT server) after some later time because you need to change it only on one place without modifying all the reports.

In Crystal Server, is there any equivalent? If not, what are the alternatives?

BTW, I'm using SAP Crystal Server 2013 and Crystal Reports 11.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**: Saw this under Database > Set Datasource Location...
[image]

Can I save Datasource in Crystal and point all my reports thru this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change data source by using Database-Set Datasource location from menu bar. From there it is pretty simple to change a reports datasource as long as you are changing to a database with same structure. If tables or fields don't exist you will receive an error. If field types used in the report do not match new data structure a mapping menu will appear.

So for example... I have several ODBC data sources which point to same server but different directories. Each directory has identical database structure but for different departments so all different data. I have setup each to be a favorite connection in database manager. I click database from menu bar, select Set Datasource. Select the current datasource. Select the new datasource and click update!

Very straight forward except for the items I mentioned in first paragraph.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I believe this approach can be time consuming if you have many reports. You'll perform this step repetitively for each the reports. BTW, saw something interesting in 'Set Datasource Location' and updated my question above. Thanks again!